# In a triangle $\Delta ABC$, find angle A if $r:R:r_1=2:5:12$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> Context: $r_1$ is the ex circle opposite angle A, $r$ is the incircle and $R$ is the circumcircle.

Let the proportionality constant be $x$

$$4R\sin A/2 \sin B/2 \sin C/2 =2x$$
$$R=5x$$
$$4R\sin A/2 \cos B/2 \cos C/2 = 12x$$

Dividing 1 and 3
$$\tan B/2 \tan C/2 =\frac 16$$

How should I solve further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to go works fine, you need after the attempt from the OP
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin\frac A2\sin \frac B2\sin \frac C2 &=\frac {2x}{4\cdot 5x}=\frac 1{10}\ ,\\
\sin\frac A2\cos \frac B2\cos \frac C2 &=\frac {12x}{4\cdot 5x}=\frac 6{10}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
just one more small step:
$$
\frac 12=
\frac 6{10}-\frac 1{10}
=\sin\frac A2
\underbrace{
\left(
\cos \frac B2\cos \frac C2
-
\sin \frac B2\sin \frac C2
\right)}
_{\displaystyle=\cos\frac{B+C}2=\sin\frac A2}
=\sin^2\frac A2
\ .
$$
So $\frac A2$ is $45^\circ$, the angle with the sine $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 2):

The area of the triangle is

$$Area = \frac12r(a+b+c) = \frac12r_1(c+b-a)= \frac {abc}{4R}$$

which leads to

$${b+c}=\frac{r_1+r}{r_1-r}a= \frac75a,\>\>\>\>\>bc=\frac{48}{25}R^2=\frac{12}{25}\frac{a^2}{\sin^2A}\tag 1$$

Reexpress the cosine rule for the triangle $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A $
as

$$(b+c)^2-a^2=2bc(1+\cos A )$$

Substitute (1) to get

$$\cos A(1+\cos A)=0$$

which yields $\cos A=0$, i.e. $A=90^\circ$.

Comment: Why don't they teach us that version of the cosine rule? It's actually much cleaner and easier to compute :)

Comment: @Plato - for this case, it is definitely more convenient

Comment: As shown by your elegant answer. You have a nice geometric intuition.

Comment: @Plato thx for the compliment

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align} 
r&=2\,k
,\quad
R=5\,k
,\quad
r_a=12\,k
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

We can find the radii $r_a,r_b$ of other two 
excircles, using known identities
\begin{align}
r_b+r_c
&=r+4\,R-r_a 
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\frac1{r_b}+\frac1{r_c}
&=\frac1r-\frac1{r_a}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

and assuming WLOG that $r_b\le r_c$,we get

\begin{align}
2+\frac{r_b}{r_c}+\frac{r_c}{r_b} 
&= \frac{25}6
,\\
\frac{r_b}{r_c}&=\frac23
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

\eqref{4} combined with \eqref{3} gives

\begin{align} 
r_b&=4\,k
,\quad
r_c=6\,k
.
\end{align}

Noe we can apply a neat expression fo find the $\cos\alpha$:

\begin{align} 
\cos\alpha&=
\frac{r_br_c-rr_a}{r_br_c+rr_a}
\end{align}
and get the answer: $\cos\alpha=0$.

Similarly, the other two are

\begin{align} 
\cos\beta &=
\frac{r_ar_c-rr_b}{r_ar_c+rr_b}
=\frac45
,\\
\cos\gamma &=
\frac{r_ar_b-rr_c}{r_ar_b+rr_c}
=\frac35
,
\end{align}

and we can conclude that the triangle
is similar to the famous $3-4-5$ right-angled triangle.